# MailKit /Google OAUTH of STMP Server throws Exception "5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye" when authenticating

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, mailkit

I am attempting to authenticate with a Google Smtp server using oAuth2.

I get this error when I attempt to Authenticate with the server:
MailKit.Security.AuthenticationException: '555: 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. g2-20020a056e021e0200b002c82a3f69cesm5461647ila.8 - gsmtp'

I have seen others get this error when attempting to send the mail, but I'm not getting that far.   The following sample app can reproduce the error.

On the Google Developer Console, I have Created a project.  I created a service account and a Key.  I have Enable the GMAIL API.

Basic Auth works, but I am preparing for google to disable Basic Auth.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit.Security;

namespace ConsoleAppToTestMail
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendMail();
        }

        private static void SendMail()
        {
            try
            {
                // service account email address
                const string serviceAccount = "my-oauth-service@smtp-support-60485.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

                // import service account key p12 certificate.
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2("C:\\Certs\\smtp-support-60485-58c02993074a.p12",
                    "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

                // G Suite user email address
                var gsuiteUser = "my-oauth-service@smtp-support-60485.iam.gserviceaccount.com";

                var serviceAccountCredentialInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccount)
                {
                    User = gsuiteUser,
                    Scopes = new[]
                    {
                        "../auth/gmail.send",
                        "https://mail.google.com/"
                    }

                }.FromCertificate(certificate);
                var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(serviceAccountCredentialInitializer);
                // request access token
                var task = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                var success = task.Result;
                if (!success)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Access token failed.");



                var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(credential.User, credential.Token.AccessToken);
                //var oauthBearer = new SaslMechanismOAuthBearer(credential.User, credential.Token.AccessToken);

                var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(new ProtocolLogger("google.smtp.log"));
                smtpClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

                smtpClient.Authenticate(oauth2);  // this is where the error occurs

                // send mail goes here

            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ep.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The Authentication token I get back is 1024 Characters. but ends with a long string of periods

ya29.c.b0AXv0zTNEf9xphDdsW_a-NtVGzk63Gj4vf4zaWyG3f-GLGOk82BREueuG41EmcjNZTo-RZxU6UWHFra2kDqv9estaLRuTDnf8yBHPYiLH2-lFYlEQcw2sxrx0BMjL3cB01IzTII5XJR6mcQxeoYLAteB_IWovLBWnYreGIiCH3PTDos4gBFSACb1KNQ4wJqomlivoBefLulE1OHyaOesCqWOnkaBcQw.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

I have also tried using OAuthBearer with the same result.

```
var oauthBearer = new SaslMechanismOAuthBearer(credential.User, credential.Token.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Get rid of the gmail.send scope.

Comment: @jstedfast - I tried removing     //"../auth/gmail.send", from scope,  it makes no difference

Comment: If you look at the protocol logs, is the AUTH command longer that 1000 characters?

Comment: You are probably hitting this: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/1343

Comment: Yes - this appears to be issue..  the Token is 1024 characters and ends with a bunch of ...'   I tried trimming the periods of the end and I don't get the syntax error, but authentication fails.

Comment: The Protocol log:S: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [144.191.148.21]
S: 250-SIZE 35882577
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: AUTH XOAUTH2 ********
S: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error, goodbye. i8-20020a0566022c8800b006463c801381sm8283721iow.48 - gsmtp

Comment: Unfortunately there's no known fix for that.